# Rxswift map + concat in parallel

Tags: swift, rx-swift

This Observable is executing the following

- Given a source observable
- we use map to perform some async work
- we use concat to return the result of the async work in order

The following is returning the desired result, but I would like to start 
the async work in parallel.

What the correct way of doing it with Rx?

```
import RxSwift

func delay(time: Int, closure: () -> Void) {
  dispatch_after(
    dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(time * Int(NSEC_PER_SEC))),
    dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

func doAsyncWork(value: Int, desc: String, time: Int) -> Observable<Int> {
  return Observable.create() { (observer) -> Disposable in
    print(desc)
    delay(time) {
      observer.onNext(value)
      observer.onCompleted()
    }
    return NopDisposable.instance
  }
}

let seq = Observable
  .of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  .map { (n) -> Observable<Int> in
    return doAsyncWork(n,
      desc: "start \(n) - wait \(5 - n)",
      time: 6 - n
    )
  }
  .concat()

let sharedSeq = seq.shareReplay(0)
sharedSeq.subscribeNext { print("=> \($0)") }
sharedSeq.subscribeCompleted { print("=> completed") }
```

This produce

```
//start 1 - wait 4
// => 1
//start 2 - wait 3
// => 2
//start 3 - wait 2
// => 3
//start 4 - wait 1
// => 4
//start 5 - wait 0
// => 5
```

The desired output would be

```
//start 1 - wait 4
//start 2 - wait 3
//start 3 - wait 2
//start 4 - wait 1
//start 5 - wait 0
// => 1
// => 2
// => 3
// => 4
// => 5
```

Comment: You say that you want to start the `Observable`s in parallel, however your desired output seems to disagree.  If they all start without delay, then shouldn't the order be `5, 4, 3, 2, 1`, since `5` waits 0 seconds, and `4` waits 1 second, etc.?

Comment: If you update your post to include a `swift` tag, your question and the answers will get syntax highlighting.

Comment: Sorry @solidcell the question was pretty vague, I edited hopefully its clearer now. My goal was to return the result of an async Work in order, but to start each async work in parallel. If keeping the order didnt matter, using flatmap as your suggested would have worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work not sure this is the best answer though

```
import RxSwift

func delay(time: Int, closure: () -> Void) {
  dispatch_after(
    dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(time * Int(NSEC_PER_SEC))),
    dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

func doAsyncWork(value: Int, desc: String, time: Int) -> Observable<Int> {
  return Observable.create() { (observer) -> Disposable in
    print(desc)
    delay(time) {
      observer.onNext(value)
      observer.onCompleted()
    }
    return NopDisposable.instance
  }
}

let seq = Observable
  .of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  .map { (n) -> Observable<Int> in
    let o = doAsyncWork(n,
      desc: "start \(n) - wait \(5 - n)",
      time: 6 - n
    ).shareReplay(1)
    o.subscribe()
    return o.asObservable()
  }
  .concat()

let sharedSeq = seq.shareReplay(0)
sharedSeq.subscribeNext { print("=> \($0)") }
sharedSeq.subscribeCompleted { print("=> completed") }
```

Comment: Yea, that's what I would suggest you do.  As you found out, the code in your question was not creating a "hot" observable, only a "cold" observable.  So by subscribing right away, the observable will begin its work.  Another variant of your solution would be to use a `Subject`, which is already a hot observable.  You would then not need the `o.subscribe`.

Answer (score 1):

Your "desired output" seems to disagree with your desire to have the `Observable`s start "in parallel", yet delay their elements such that "5" has no delay, "4" has a 1 second delay, "3" has a 2 second delay, etc.

I would think you're looking for this output:

```
start 1 - wait 4
start 2 - wait 3
start 3 - wait 2
start 4 - wait 1
start 5 - wait 0
5
4
3
2
1
```

This is something you could use to do that:

```
Observable.range(start: 1, count: 5)
    .flatMap { n -> Observable<Int> in
        let waitInterval = 5 - n
        print("start \(n) - wait \(waitInterval)")
        return Observable.just(n)
            .delaySubscription(RxTimeInterval(waitInterval), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    }
    .subscribeNext { i in
        print(i)
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

If you meant something else, you could probably easily tweak this snippet to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

This won't help you right now, but maybe it will help others in the future.

The operator you're looking for is called `concatMap`.  However, at the moment, it doesn't exist in `RxSwift`.

There currently exists a closed PR for it [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/pull/403).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this doesn't work as you expected is that `concat` subscribes to the source observables *one at a time*, waiting for the first to finish before it subscribes to the second and so on.

In RxJava there is `concatEager`, which does what you want - subscribe to all sources at the start while still preserving order. But not in Swift it seems.

What you could do is zip each item with its index, flatMap, sort on index and unzip.